# MvvmCross bind to progress indicator in MvxDialogViewController

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have a MvxDialogViewController and I'm trying to use the progress indicator shown in the Xamarin example by adding bindable properties.

I can get the indicator to appear when I set Visble to true programatically but not when I bind to a vm property.

Here is the view code:

```
var bindings = this.CreateInlineBindingTarget<LoginViewModel>();

Root = new RootElement("Login")
{
    new Section("Login Credentials")
    {
        new EntryElement("Username", "Enter user name").Bind(bindings, vm => vm.UserName),
        new EntryElement("Password", "Enter password", "", true).Bind(bindings, vm => vm.Password)
    }
};

_bindableProgress = new BindableProgress(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds).Bind(bindings, b => b.Visible, vm => vm.IsBusy);
_bindableProgress.Title = "Logging in...";
View.Add(_bindableProgress);
```

I also tried to bind like this:

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<LoginView, LoginViewModel>();
set.Bind(_bindableProgress).For(b => b.Title).To(vm => vm.ProgressTitle);
set.Bind(_bindableProgress).For(b => b.Visible).To(vm => vm.IsBusy);
set.Apply();
```

But neither way worked.

Here is by BindableProgress class:

```
public class BindableProgress : UIView
{
    private UIActivityIndicatorView _activitySpinner;
    private UILabel _loadingLabel;

    public string Title { get; set; }

    private bool _visible;
    public bool Visible
    {
        get { return _visible; }
        set
        {
            _visible = value;
            if (_visible)
            {
                Show();
            }
            else
            {
                Hide();
            }
        }
    }

    public BindableProgress(RectangleF frame) : base(frame)
    {
        // configurable bits
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
        Alpha = 0;
        AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleDimensions;

        float labelHeight = 22;
        float labelWidth = Frame.Width - 20;

        // derive the center x and y
        float centerX = Frame.Width/2;
        float centerY = Frame.Height/2;

        // create the activity spinner, center it horizontally and put it 5 points above center x
        _activitySpinner = new UIActivityIndicatorView(UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge);
        _activitySpinner.Frame = new RectangleF(
            centerX - (_activitySpinner.Frame.Width / 2),
            centerY - _activitySpinner.Frame.Height - 20,
            _activitySpinner.Frame.Width,
            _activitySpinner.Frame.Height);
        _activitySpinner.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleMargins;
        AddSubview(_activitySpinner);


        // create and configure the label
        _loadingLabel = new UILabel(new RectangleF(
            centerX - (labelWidth/2),
            centerY + 20,
            labelWidth,
            labelHeight
            ));
        _loadingLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        _loadingLabel.TextColor = UIColor.White;
        _loadingLabel.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        _loadingLabel.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleMargins;
        AddSubview(_loadingLabel);
    }

    private void Show()
    {
        _loadingLabel.Text = Title;
        Alpha = 0.75f;
        _activitySpinner.StartAnimating();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Fades out the control and then removes it from the super view
    /// </summary>
    private void Hide()
    {
        _activitySpinner.StopAnimating();

        Animate(
            0.5, // duration
            () => { Alpha = 0; },
            () => { RemoveFromSuperview(); }
            );
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

My vm property looks like this

```
private bool _isBusy;
public bool IsBusy
{
    get { return _isBusy; }
    set { _isBusy = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsBusy); }
}
```

It works fine in Android so I'm guessing the problem in not with that.

Comment: What does your vm property look like?  Are you calling RaisePropertyChanged when you set your busy property?  Any weird stuff in your debug trace?

Comment: I have updated the question to include the vm property. Pretty sure the issue is not with that. I'll check out the debug trace.

Answer (score 0):

`IsBusy` is probably false at binding time. So `_visible` is set to `false` and `Hide()` is called. Now the view is removed from the superview and you can't show it anymore, because `Show()` doesn't add it to the superview again. Try to omit the `RemoveFromSuperview();`. Or modify the `Visible` property like this:

```cs
public bool Visible
{
    get { return _visible; }
    set
    {
        if(_visible == value) 
            return;

        _visible = value;
        if (_visible)
        {
            Show();
        }
        else
        {
            Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds promising. Will try it out when I get back to work on Tuesday.

Comment: Made the change and still didn't work. I have it working now but I had to create a wrapper class, bind to that and set Visible from that. For some reason MvvmCross did not want to bind to the BindableProgress class - perhaps you can not bind to one view from another.